# datetimepicker not auto close

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

Here's the view :

```html
 <div id="datetimepicker2" class="input-append" style="resize: none;" data-autoclose="true">
                        <label class="control-label"><h3 style="color: #821571;font-family: 'Philosopher',sans-serif;">Tanggal dan Waktu</h3></label><br />
                        <input data-format="MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm PP" type="text" class="form-control" id="pickup" name="pickup" style="height:50px; width: auto;" placeholder="Klik icon sebelah kanan"></input>
                        <span class="add-on" style="height: 50px;">
                        <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar" style="height: 50px;"></i>
                        </span>
                    </div>
```

And the js :

```js
$(function() 
    {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker
        ({
            pick12HourFormat: true,
            language: 'en'
        });
    });
```

When I choose the date and click anywhere outside the input form, the datetimepicker close, but when I choose the time and click anywhere outside, it's not autoclose. How can I fix it?

Answer (score -2):

Add the option `autoclose: true`:

```
$(function() 
    {
        $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker
        ({
            autoclose: true
        });
    });
```

Comment: ops, sorry! I had the same problem today with that but with `datepicker` instead of `datetimepicker`

Comment: but seems that is the same option, what plugin are you using?

Comment: from tarruda datetimepicker bootstrap

Comment: i have the best approach for this, I separated the date and time input. Now, my problem is how to insert date and time format to mysql?